# Object doesn't support property or method 'text'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get the error in the title when I call `setDefaultLocalPrinter()`. If I call the span b y its ID like this `$("#spanId").text("test")` then it works, but it doesn't work like below

```
<span id="defaultLocalPrinterName<c:out value="${entry.index}"/>">Printer</span>

function setDefaultLocalPrinter(printerName) {
        console.log("setDefaultLocalPrinter: " + printerName)
        $('span[id^="defaultLocalPrinterName"]').each(function(){
            this.text(printerName)
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `$(this)` inside `each()`.

```
$(this).text(printerName);
```

`this` is plain JavaScript object. It cannot be used to call method which is defined on the jQuery prototype. `$(this)` is `this` wrapped in jQuery that have access to all the methods & properties defined on the jQuery prototype.

If you want to use plain JavaScript,

```
this.textContent = printerName;
```

---

`each` is not even needed, the `textContent` can be directly set using `text()` on selector.

```
$('span[id^="defaultLocalPrinterName"]').text(printerName);
```